# Why do "a+1" and "&a+1" give different results when "a" is an int array?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

    printf("a = %u , &a = %u\n",a,&a);
    printf("a+1 = %u , &a+1 = %u\n",a+1,&a+1);
}
```

how a and &a are internally interpreted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, a is the address of the first element of the array, and &a is the address of the array, but obviously they both have the same address.

However when you add (or subtract) a number from a pointer the compiler takes the size of the data into consideration thus in your case (assuming the size of int is 4 bytes) a+1 will be bigger than a by 4 because you move the pointer one integer ahead, but &a+1 would be bigger by 40 because you more the pointer one ARRAY OF 10 INTEGERS ahead.

Answer (score 21):

Both statements print out addresses and are probably meant to explain pointer arithmetic.

`a` and `&a` are NOT the same, they have different types, but hold the same memory address.

`&a` is of type `int (*)[10]` (which acts like a pointer to an array)
`a` is of type `int [10]` (which acts like a pointer to a single element)

So when you add 1 keep those types in mind.  The pointer will be offset by the size of the type that the address contains.  `a+1` offsets by the size of int, i.e. to the second element in the array.  `&a+1` offsets completely past the whole array.

Comment: That is almost all what type in C is about: arithmetic and size.

Comment: For completeness, it would be nice to add that `&a[0]` is of type `int *` and will act very much like `a`.

Comment: @Brian R.Bondy SO we can use `sizeof` to show out those differences in their types?