# Find the length of string in c with just one line of code without using strlen() function?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to find if there is any way to find the length of any string in `C`.

*Here's how I did:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[10] = "hello";
    int i , len = 0;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        len++
    }
    printf("length of string is: %d" , len);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to find, **if there is any way to get the length of string in just one line of code.**

Comment: A call to `strlen` is a one-liner

Comment: I want to find a way without using external functions.

Comment: Rather a silly question since C does not care about lines at all. The preprocessor does though. That means your entire program can be just two lines: the include and the main function.

Comment: Also the shortest code in C is far from the fastest code. The `strlen` function is probably optimized with vector instructions such as SSE4.2, like here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/38004910/

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395821/how-to-determine-the-length-of-a-string-without-using-strlen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just simply do this:

```
for(len = 0; s[len] != '\0'; len++);
```

So in just one line of code you will get the length of string stored in **len**.

Comment: If OP already declares `int len = 0` at the beginning of `main()`, then `for (; s[len] != '\0'; len++);` also works.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove `s[len] != '\0';` comparison to make it shorter:

```
for(len=0;s[len];len++);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call **strlen()** function to know length of the string in one line.
it returns an size value **size_t strlen(char*)**

Comment: I want to find the length without using the strlen() function.

Comment: The OP was pretty clear that he wanted something that *does not use strlen()*

Comment: `strlen()` actually returns `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Thanks buddy!  @RoadRunner

Answer (score 2):

just do this:

```
for(len=0;s[len];len++);
```

this will store the length in `len`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one line, the something like this is also possible:

```
while (s[len] != '\0') len++;
```

Which is just another way of doing it, but not most pleasing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The most minimal version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[10] = "hello", *p = s;

  while(*p++); /* "counting" here */

  printf("The length of string '%s' is: %td" , s, p - s);
}
```

It prints:

```
The length of string 'hello' is: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this should be the shortest version:

```
for(l=-1;s[++l];);
```

It's 18 bytes, so it's quite a good code-golf answer. However, I would prefer the more canonical

```
for(len = 0; s[len]; len++) ;
```

in real code.