# Pointer arithmetic and address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I have come across a code which goes like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1);
 int *ptr2 = (int*) &a;
 ptr2 +=1 ;
 printf("%d %d %d \n", *(a + 1),*(ptr - 1) ,*ptr2 );
 return 0;
}
```

The pointer arithmetic does it for me except this line :

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1);
```

Is it undefined behaviour ?
Why do we get `5` on dereferencing `*(ptr - 1)` ?

Comment: `int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 };` is a very bad thing to do!!

Comment: @jsn My bad ! It was only 5 elements in the question , I did some weird testing before copying the code here , I will change it :) but the question stays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it out!

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
printf("%#x, %#x, %#x, %#x\n", a, &a, a+1, &a+1);

0xbfa4038c, 0xbfa4038c, 0xbfa40390, 0xbfa403a0
```

So what does that tell us?

`0xbfa4038c == 0xbfa4038c` which means `a == &a`. This is the address of the first element in the array or `a[0]`.

We know that the size of an int is 4, and you know that `*(a+1)` == `a[1]` (the second element in the array) and this is proven by:

`0xbfa4038c + 0x4 = 0xbfa40390` which means `a + one int = address of the next element`

Thus if we see `&a+1 == 0xbfa403a0`, that means we're `((0xa0-0x8c)/4)` = 5 elements into the array. You know that `a[5]` is invalid, so that means we're one passed the end of the array.

so if you take:

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1); //one passed last element in the array
printf("%d",*(ptr - 1));//back up one, or last element in the array and deference
```

That's why you get `5`

Comment: +1 Got  it ! I am still confused over a tiny bit ! a and &a gives the  address but adding 1 to both gives us different results . &a+1 adds 5 ints as the sizeof(a) is 5*sizeof(int) but why not a+1 ?

Comment: The +1 is adding one to the address based on TYPE. Try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989370/why-do-a1-and-a1-give-different-results-when-a-is-an-int-array) as an answer to your question (not the selected answer, the one with more votes is clearer)

Answer (score 3):

The size of `a` is "5 `int`s". So `&a + 1` refers to the first memory location *past* all of `a`, since the pointer arithmetic is done in units of the size of `a`.

Comment: int *ptr = (int *)(&a[0] + 1);  // second element of the array a

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes? Not sure if that was meant as a counter-argument ... That works since the `+ 1` then applies to the result of `&a[0]`, and the type of that is plain `int`.

Comment: @unwind I think he posted that as a fix to OP.

Comment: @unwind +1  Well explained :)

Comment: @unwind I have understood it but on contrary why does `*(a+1)` gives 2 ? here the sizeof(a) is 5 ints and a is also a pointer to the first element so shouldnt it give us undefined behaviour ie out of range ? *(ptr - 1) is justified by giving sizeof(ptr) to be an int .

Comment: @user1471, (a+1) is the same as a[1].  You are treating the array a as a pointer and you are doing one past the pointer.  so *(a) is the same as a[0] and *(a+1) is the same as a[1], etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

For an array of n elements of type T, then the address of the first element has type ‘pointer to T’; [the address of the whole array](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html) has type ‘pointer to array of n elements of type T’;

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1); //&a-> address whole array, size=20 bytes, 
         //ptr=&a+1: next element =adress of a +20 bytes.
         //ptr - 1 = address of a +16 = address of last a's element = address of 5
```