# What's the difference between a and a + 0 as C pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Look at the  C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int v[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("%d\n", v);
    printf("%d\n", v + 0);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(v));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(v + 0));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(v + 1));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(v + 2));
    return 0;
}
```

Here's one of the outputs:

```
-587904464
-587904464
12
8
8
8
```

I think v is the same as v + 0.

Both are pointers pointing to the first element in array v[3].

Therefore, v and v+0 have the same value.

But why do they fail to hold the same bytes?  (sizeof(v) and sizeof(v + 0) are different )

Comment: it's the same reason ["a+1" and "&a+1" give different results when "a" is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2989370/995714)\

Comment: You can't print addresses with `%d`. You must use `%p` and cast the argument to ptr-to-void.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An array identifier decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, in *most* cases. But, when an array is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, this conversion does not take place, and the operator yields the size of the array in bytes. [From §6.3.2.1 ¶3 of the C11 Draft Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3):

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, the **_Alignof** operator, or the unary **&** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Note that in the C18 Standard the `_Alignof` operator has been removed from this passage ([discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51804165/6879826)).

So, `sizeof(v)` yields the size of the array `v[]` in bytes, which is 12 bytes. That is, the *type* of the operand is `int [3]` since the array has not been converted to a pointer to `int` (as it would be in most expressions), and the `sizeof` operator yields the size of this type (an array of 3 `int`s) in bytes.

But with `sizeof (v + 0)` the *type* of the expression `v + 0` determines the result yielded by the `sizeof` operator. In the expression `v + 0`, the array `v[]` decays to a pointer to the first element of `v[]`, and then `0` is added according to the rules of pointer arithmetic. The result is a pointer to `int` (since `&v[0]` is itself a pointer to `int`), so the type of the expression `v + 0` is `int *`. The `sizeof` operator thus yields the size of a pointer to `int` in this case. The same holds for the similar expressions `sizeof (v + 1)`, etc.

As an aside, note that you must print addresses with the `%p` conversion specifier after first casting to `void *` to avoid undefined behavior:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)v);
printf("%p\n", (void *)(v + 0));
```

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- thanks for the link; I was too lazy to find it when I wrote the answer at first, but I have added it now ;)