# Pointer Arithmetic - Issues with array and pointer to an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I've switched to C recently and was trying to figure out pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *a = &arr;

    printf("Array : %p\n", arr);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Value and Address of Element - %d : %d\t%p,\n", i+1, arr[i], &arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Pointer to the Array : %p\n", a);
    printf("Value pointed by the pointer : %d\n", *a);
    a = (&a+1);
    printf("Pointer after incrementing : %p\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the following line doesn't seem to work.

```
a = (&a+1);
```

After printing the incremented value of the pointer a, it still points to the array (arr).
Here's the output of the program:

```
Array : 0x7ffe74e5d390
Value and Address of Element - 1 : 1    0x7ffe74e5d390,
Value and Address of Element - 2 : 2    0x7ffe74e5d394,
Value and Address of Element - 3 : 3    0x7ffe74e5d398,
Value and Address of Element - 4 : 4    0x7ffe74e5d39c,
Value and Address of Element - 5 : 5    0x7ffe74e5d3a0,
Pointer to the Array : 0x7ffe74e5d390
Value pointed by the pointer : 1
Pointer after incrementing : 0x7ffe74e5d390
```

As you can see the pointer 'a' still points to the first element. However, in theory shouldn't 'a' point to whatever's after the last element (Given that &a + 1 increments the pointer by the size of the entire array - source: [difference between a+1 and &a+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989370/why-do-a1-and-a1-give-different-results-when-a-is-an-int-array))

Could someone explain why?

Comment: `int *a = &arr;` should not compile.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, and there is no language called "C/C++".

Comment: Make sure to enable all warnings, and treat warnings as errors, especially if you are a beginner in those languages. Even then, both C and C++ have plenty of ways in which you can write invalid programs that are still not rejected by the compiler.

Comment: @molbdnilo not sure, but I could imagine that it is fine in C.

Comment: It may be helpful to try you code on https://godbolt.org/ with mutliple comilers - often the error messages differ, and some compiler communicates the problem clearer than another.

Comment: For C++, compilation of the line `int *a = &arr;` fails with an error, for C this is "only" a warning, example from clang 10: `"warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int (*)[5]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]"`

Comment: `&a` is an `int**`, so pointer arithmetic is in units of `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Relevant answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830108/2513200

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for pointing out. I should have been more specific. I've switched to C++ and someone recommended I start with C and then move on to C++, as some of the underlying concepts (such as pointers) are same. And to be clear, this code was written in C.

Comment: @molbdnilo: There is no rule in the C standard that says that code should not compile. The C standard says the C implementation must give a warning for `int *a = &arr;`, but the standard explicitly says the code may be compiled anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = (&a+1);` sets `a` to point to one “thing” beyond **the address of `a`**.

Earlier, your code sets `a` to `&arr`, using `int *a = &arr;`. (This violates standard C constraints because the type of `&arr` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to an `int`. The correct definition would be `int *a = arr;`.) I suspect your intent in `a = (&a+1);` was to set `a` to point to one beyond where it currently points. However, correct code for this would be `a = a+1;`. That takes the **value** of `a`, adds one to it, and assigns the result to `a`.
In contrast, `a = (&a+1);` uses the address of `a` instead of its value.

This results in `a` pointing to one beyond wherever `a` is in memory. In your experiment, it seems that the array `arr` happened to be there, and your C implementation behaved accordingly.

(That explains the results you observed, but it is not behavior you should rely on. The C standard does not define what happens when you misuses pointers in this way, and various things, including compiler optimization, can cause programs to behave as if `&a+1` did not point to `arr` even if `arr` is in fact located at the address `&a+1` in memory.)

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much. 
And yes my intent was to make 'a' point to the memory location beyond the arrays bound. This is one of the reasons why I decided to learn C++, so that I could understand how things work at lower levels (how memory works).

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case the variable and the array may be placed on the stack like below, that is not guaranteed by the standard. Each cell is int. Do you remember the stack address is reduced on each local var placed.

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|a|1|2|3|4|5|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

`&a+1`, it is not the address of the array, you take the address of a, move on one cell and get the address of the array as a result.

Comment: Yes, this is a plausible explanantion of the observed behavior on many popular platforms. It is, however, in no way guaranteed.

Comment: @S.M. That's exactly what I thought it would do too. But then I found this explanation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989370/why-do-a1-and-a1-give-different-results-when-a-is-an-int-array), and was wondering what causes this to behave differently.

Comment: @RonnyRoy the difference to that question is that you assign the pointer to the array to a variable of type `int*`(which raises a warning). Due to this step, you loose the type information that this used to be an array of size 5, and the arithmetic is performed on an `int**`(in `(&a+1)`).